# Zeep : Prevalidate with type checking

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, lxml, zeep

Is there way to validate payload with type-checking with zeep? Zeep checks for missing elements but sends payload even when type is incorrect.

Example, I have element:

```xml
<element name="order_date" type="dateTime" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

When I make send wrong type, ex `'1.0'` for that field, zeep still accepts it. Later on I get `zeep.exceptions.Fault` back because SOAP server rejects my requests because of this wrong type as it has to be date in ISO format

I have kind of find a way to do it by pre-creating message and then validating it with schema provided in `wsdl` file with `lxml` library. This works well but I am not sure if I am using `zeep` in correct way, maybe it also supports it out of the box ? I have went through source code and I didn't find too much. I know that `zeep` uses type checking to translate SOAP responses back to Python but not sure about pre-validation.

My current way to deal with this:

```py
# There are some missing variables, don't want to CP everything
from lxml import etree as ET

def get_xmlschema():
    wsdl_file = ...
    wsdl_tree = ET.fromstring(wsdl_file)
    return ET.XMLSchema(wsdl_tree.find('.//schema:schema', namespaces=NAMESPACES))


def prevalidate_soap_message(client, operation, *args, **kwargs):
    # zeep checks only required elements and doesn't perform type checking
    msg = client.create_message(client.service, operation, *args, **kwargs)
    payload = msg.find('*/')
    get_xmlschema().assertValid(payload)
```

And this is how I send my payload for context:

```py
client = zeep.Client(wsdl)
operation = client.service[operation_name]
payload = ... # this is python object with structure as in wsdl schema for that operation
result = operation(payload) # it raises ValidationError if elements are missing but not for types
```